# How to ensure that data pointed by raw pointer does not get altered in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

A class contains a private data member- a raw pointer that points to some data.

Now, when I pass an object of that class to a member function of that same class as `const`, it seems that member function can change the data pointed by that raw pointer. What is the solution for this?

```
class Mystring{
 private:
    char* str;

Mystring(const Mystring &source) : str{nullptr} 
{
    source.str[0]='h';
    str = new char[std::strlen(source.str )+ 1];
    std::strcpy(str, source.str);
}
```

The code runs without any error even if I modify the data pointed to by the raw pointer. The `const` qualifier before the function parameter guarantees that you cannot change the pointer value, but how to guarantee that I cannot change the data pointed by the pointer, not the pointer itself?

Comment: `const char* str:`

Comment: const-qualifying `Mystring` is no different than const-qualifying a pointer to non-const data. It means you can't rebind the pointer to a different address, but you can modify what data is located at that fixed address.

Comment: Is there a case where you want to modify the pointed-to object *without* modifying the pointer? That would be a significant complication. (Otherwise you could just drop in a single `const` and get what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Making the object `const` means the pointer inside the object can't be changed, but the data it points to can be changed since the data is not `const`.

So, to do what you are asking for, you need to declare the pointer as pointing to `const` data, eg:

```
const char* str;
// or
char const *str;
```

Note that doing so, the statements `source.str[0]='h';` and `std::strcpy(str, source.str);` will no longer work when using `str` as the destination. So, you will have to initialize your data before you assign it to the `str` pointer, eg:

```
class Mystring{
private:
    const char* str;

    Mystring(const Mystring &source) : str{nullptr} {
        char *new_str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) + 1];
        std::strcpy(new_str, source.str);
        //new_str[0]='h';
        str = new_str;
    }
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class Mystring{
private:
    const char* str;

    const char* copystr(const Mystring &source) {
        char *new_str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) + 1];
        std::strcpy(new_str, source.str);
        //new_str[0]='h';
        return new_str;
    }

    Mystring(const Mystring &source) : str{copystr(source)} { }
};
```